# how to make a popover display its full length when its parent div is small than the length of the popover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am appending `divs` when a button is clicked. Everytime a `div` is appended, an icon appends within it as well. When i click the icon, a popover pops. Now the div itself has a smaller height than the popover. How can I go around this? The div;s height will increase only when `li` is appended within it. If its not appended then the `div` height will not increase

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruju/je9vth3f/4/)

Comment: Which `icon` ? i can't see any icon

Comment: `< i class = "fa fa-ellipsis">` is the icon i have in html. its also present in JFiddle. I had imported it from `FontAwesome icons` and I have also imported the `link ` for `fontawesome`

Comment: I added `cart` and `list` but didn't see any icon, are you sure it's show on jsfiddle?

Comment: let me change the icon to something  else and then share the link again

Comment: i have added the edited code's link

Comment: The link is same, check it again

Comment: let me upload it again.. I dont know why its the same

Comment: Try to update it *via update button* then share the new link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ruju/je9vth3f/4/      This should work

Comment: Well well, now we got something, so what you trying to achieve? you want to change height of appended div equal by popover? or what?

Comment: I want the entire popover to be shown. When I run it on my laptop its not been shown. but the same works nicely in JSFiddle

Comment: So, it's need responsive design, you should change popover position on different resolution.like `Trello`.